# Bookshelf.js lifecycle events not occurring in expected order

Tags: promise, bookshelf.js

My initialize events are not running in the expected order.

I have the following lifecycle event listeners in my Bookshelf model:

```
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('saving', this.validate);
    this.on('creating', this.generateId);
    this.on('creating', this.hashPassword);
    this.on('creating', this.generateUsername);
  }
```

I return a Promise in the 'generateUsername' method. According to the logs, this Promise completes after the 'validate' method is run.

I was under the impression that the lifecycle events are Promise-aware and would wait for the Promise to complete before proceeding. What am I doing wrong?

Lifecycle methods:

```
generateId: function() {
    this.set('id', shortid.generate());

  },

  hashPassword: function() {
      /* eslint-disable no-invalid-this */
    return bcrypt.genSaltAsync(12).bind(this)
      .then(function(salt) {
        return bcrypt.hashAsync(this.get('password'), salt);
      })
      .then(function(hash) {
        this.set('password', hash);
      });
  },

  generateUsername: function(model, attr, options) {
    var email = this.get('email');
    if (!email) {
      this.set('username', shortid.generate());
      return;
    }

    var username = email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@')).replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]/g, '');
    if (!username) {
      this.set('username', shortid.generate());
      return;
    }

    var self = this;
    return User.where('username', '=', username)
        .fetch()
        .then(function(found) {
          if (!found) {
            self.set('username', username);
            winston.info('setting username to [%s]', username);
          } else {
            self.set('username', username + shortid.generate());
            winston.info('setting username to [%s]', self.get('username'));
          }
    });
  },

  validate: function() {
    return checkit.run(this.attributes);
  }
```

Logs:

```
info: Validation errors { username: [ 'The username is required' ],
  ageGroup: [ 'The ageGroup is required' ],
  bodyType: [ 'The bodyType is required' ] }
info: setting username to [nim_sathiVyxIkm--Hx]
```

Comment: These events seem to be at the same level. Documentation doesn't clearly state that handlers will be executed serially. I would create a github issue to ask about this and make the docs clearly.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect ordering of events was reported as an [issue in Bookshelf](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1894) and fixed in version 0.13.0 that was released in the 18th of March, 2018, so your code should work as expected now.